# How to use different @Entity("parameter", expr="repository.customQuery()") with multiple routes

Tags: symfony, routes, doctrine, symfony4

In my controller, I have multiple route set for one action.
They all need same content, but are on différent URLs.

One of the route have no parameters, while the second have 1 parameter.
Thus, my custom query change based on whether or not the parameter is present.

Rather than make two different action, with mostly same code, I would like, if possible, to handle it with `@Entity` and `expr`.

The goal here would be to do `custonQuery({isAccueil: true}` if route is `salle_home`,
else `customQuery({salle: id})` if route is `salle_show`

Is it possible to use a different expression based on the route?

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="salle_home", methods={"GET"})
 * @Route("/hall-{id}", name="salle_show", methods={"GET"})
 * @Entity("salle", expr="repository.customQuery()")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Salle|null $salle
 * @return Response
 */
public function show(Request $request, Salle $salle=null): Response {
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know (I wouldn't think so), but even if it's not possible, you could extract the common logic to a function and pass the `$salle` variable around from your two routes.

Comment: Just split the actions for `GET /` (entity collection) and `GET /hall-{id}` (entity-by-id) into two separate methods. Keep things simple. Just my few cents. Thank me later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow Nicolai's advice.
If you don't, you can try with [`ParamConverter`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) that is a shortcut for `@Entity` annotation.
I suppose - but didn't tried - that naming the parameter (in your case `id`) would left out `Salle` entity when `id` is not matched in the route.

Comment: Yep, will do. Just wanted to figure out if it was possible